# Json object iteration Angular 2

Tags: html, json, angular, typescript

I am having problem iterating to through json object.

Here is the Json sample:
**floors.ts**

```
this.floors= [
      {
            floorName: "floor 1",
            result: [
                {
                    resFloor: "1",
                    floorResult: [
                        {
                            roomNum: "room 1",
                            roomResult: [
                                {
                                    bedNum: "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    bedNum: "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    bedNum: "3"
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                        {
                            roomNum: "room 2",
                            roomResult: [
                                {
                                    bedNum: "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    bedNum: "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    bedNum: "3"
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                        {
                            roomNum: "room 3",
                            roomResult: [
                                {
                                    bedNum: "1"
                                },
                                {
                                    bedNum: "2"
                                },
                                {
                                    bedNum: "3"
                                }
                            ],
                        },
                    ],
                }
            ],
        }
  ]
```

**floor-template.html**

```
<button *ngFor="let i of floors">
{{i.floorName}}
<div *ngIf="clicked">
  <button *ngFor="let j of i.result">
    {{j.resFloor}}
    <div *ngIf="clicked">
      <button *ngFor="let k of j.floorResult">
        {{k.roomNum}}
      </button>
    </div>
  </button>
 </div>
```

What I am trying to do is that I want to iterate through this json. In ngIf, clicked is boolean and if it is set to true then it gives me result for all ngFor loops and then it gives me an error; and if it is set to false then nothing comes up except the result of 1st for loop and then that button is doing nothing. What am I doing wrong. Please point into the right direction. Thanks!!

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: @Amit I am getting this error  `EXCEPTION: Cannot read property 'floorResult' of undefined`

Comment: Can you post your entire json?

Comment: @Amit I have edited floors.ts

Comment: Hmm, I suggest commenting out the problematic ngFor and outputting {{j | json}} and see what it looks like from inside the ngFor. Let me know if it looks different than it should (or not)

Answer (score 2):

Your condition is not working correctly. This works for me on the first click. (I have went no further)

HTML

```
 <button *ngFor="let i of floors" (click)="wasClicked()">
        {{i.floorName}}
        <div *ngIf="clicked === true">
            <button *ngFor="let j of i.result">
                {{j.resFloor}}
                <div *ngIf="clicked">
                    <button *ngFor="let k of j.floorResult">
                        {{k.roomNum}}
                    </button>
                </div>
            </button>
        </div>
    </button>
```

Typescript - declare a clicked variable and write this function

```
wasClicked() {
    this.clicked = true;
    console.log('clicked: ' + this.clicked);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, so I got all the button using your name method but do you know how can I do this: if I click on the floorName button only then the resFloor for loop should run and this should happen in the rest of the for loop. Thanks

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you're going for but try this. It only displays a box with a one when floor1 is clicked and then if that box is clicked it displays the rooms. You will need to declare another boolean and another wasClicked() function.

<button *ngFor="let i of floors" (click)="wasClicked()">
 {{i.floorName}}
 <div *ngIf="clicked === true">
  <button *ngFor="let j of i.result" (click)="wasClicked2()">
   {{j.resFloor}}
   <div *ngIf="clicked2 === true">
    <button *ngFor="let k of j.floorResult">
     {{k.roomNum}}
    </button>
   </div>
  </button>
 </div>
</button>

Comment: Did this do what you needed?

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating in a wrong way, because you might think that you second loop depends of the first one but not, they are different, so when you tried to access the second loop, i is equal to undefined.

Try something like this

```
<div *ngFor="let i of floors">
    {{i.floorName}}
    <div *ngIf="clicked">
        <div *ngFor="let j of i.result">
            {{j.resFloor}}
            <div *ngIf="clicked">
                <span *ngFor="let k of j.floorResult">{{k.roomNum}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

also, I changed the html elements as you were using them incorrectly, button shouldn't contain div elements.

[image]